# Glide not animating ImageView loaded from cache

Tags: android, imageview, handler, android-glide

I'm using Glide as my imageloader,and want images to fade in the background. The problem that I'm having is that it doesn't animate once the image has been shown once already.

```
int i = 0;
int[] images = {
        R.drawable.sunset1,R.drawable.sunset2,R.drawable.sunset3
}; 

if(i < images.length - 1){
 i++;
}else{
 i = 0;
}
Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(images[i]).placeholder(imageView.getDrawable()).crossFade(1000).into(imageView);
```

Comment: It looks like you may have already opened an issue on GitHub, but if not, check out: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/241

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's expected behavior for Glide. If you look at the source code for the `animate` method, there is this text in the comment:

> Will only be run if the resource was loaded asynchronously (ie was not in the memory cache)

To get around it, you can simply use the `ImageView#startAnimation` method to have the image animate.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

Add this with glide implementation:

```
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
```

for example:

```
Glide.with(requireContext())
              .load(imageUrl)
              .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
              .skipMemoryCache(true)
              .into(it)
```

There is another option to solve this, If you are able to identify image changes then give your new file the name below:

```
.signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(MY_FILE_NAME)))
```

If you want to load the image every time with the latest images, use this:

```
.signature(new StringSignature(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
```